# what's wrong with this model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to develop a module for getting  data from mongodb, I already have other models working in my application, but this one does not, this is my schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ProvinciaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
"nome":String,
"tc_provincia_id":Number,
"id" : Number,
"codice_regione" : Number,
"codice" : Number,
"sigla" : Number
},{collection:'province'})
module.exports = ProvinciaSchema;
```

this is my  model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ProvinciaSchema = require('../schemas/provincia');
var Provincia = mongoose.model('provincia', ProvinciaSchema);
module.exports = Provincia;
```

This  is how I use the  model:

```
var Provincia = require('../../models/provincia');
Provincia.find({},next( err, province){
if (err){console.log('errorre whoosh '+err);
     return next(err,province)
     }
     if (!province){console.log('trovato nulla')}
     console.log('callback tc_istat_id')
     return next(err,province)
 })
```

where

```
next =function(err,prov){
    t.equivalent(out,expect)
    t.end()
```

when I launch the test if the condition argument is correct, the execution stuck at Provincia.find and the callback function it is not executed, if I put a wrong  condition the section of the code of if(err) is executed, I think there  is a problem with my schemas abnd models, but I do not understand what.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function myFunction(callback) {
       Provincia.find({},next( err, province){
            if (err) {
                console.log('errorre whoosh '+err);
                return next(err,province)
             }
            if (!province){
                console.log('trovato nulla');
                return false;
            }
            console.log('callback tc_istat_id')


            callback(err,province)
       })
 }

 myFunction(function(err,prov){
     t.equivalent(out,expect)
     t.end()
 });
```

I had no way of testing this but it is how I would set up my callback function. Let me know what you log, and what errors your get if this does not work

Comment: Hi, if the condition is {}  node just executes till  Provincia.find({},next... and after a wile I receive this:   TAP version 13
# check 1 regione
not ok 1 Timeout!
  ---
    file:   timers.js
    line:   110
    column: 15
    stack:  
      - getCaller (/home/arpho/Projects/MMASGIS6/node/mmasgis/node_modules/tap/lib/tap-assert.js:418:17)
      - assert (/home/arpho/Projects/MMASGIS6/node/mmasgis
      - Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
  ...

1..1
# tests 1
# fail  1